# Store more than 1 value in python array?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to store more than 1 value in a python array(I am open to any other data structure too).

For example :

```
array[1][2][3] = 1  # (this is what I am able to do now)
```

But later I also get the value 2, now instead of storing it in another array using the same indices, I want to be able to do this :

```
array[1][2][3] = 1,2
```

But I dont want to concatenate the existing result like in a string, and split the string to get the individual values.

Is there a way of doing this without having to introduce another dimension to the array?

edit : I want a neater way to store 2 values in the same cell.

Thanks

Comment: uh.. I don't understand what you want to do. Do you know about tuples? Wrap the RHS in parens.

Comment: what's wrong with what you're doing now?

Comment: Python doesn't have arrays. It his lists, and lists-of-lists, and (like you have here) lists-of-lists-of-lists. Certainly it can have lists-of-lists-of-lists-of-lists.

Comment: @erip: why would adding parentheses change anything?

Comment: @erip I use them in separate parenthesis?

Comment: @DSM TIL. :) Guess you don't need them.

Comment: Parentheses are only necessary to define an empty tuple (`()`) and to disambiguate (e.g., the two-item list `[1,2]` vs the one-item list `[(1,2)]`). It's the comma that actually creates the tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know all the contents a priori you may use a tuple. Here I will create pairs of numbers `(n, n+1)` and store them in a list:

```
>>> l = [(n,n+1) for n in xrange(0,4)]
>>> l
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

If you decide you want to append another value, you can. Assume you want to append `3` to the tuple `(1,2)`:

```
>>> l[1] = l[1] + (3,)
>>> l
[(0, 1), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Tuples are immutable, so they're faster than lists for construction, but you can't make changes to an instantiated tuple - you must replace it. If you're fairly certain your data won't change, use a tuple. If it will (and often), use a list.

## Edit

If you want the values from the tuple, you can do the following:

```
>>> tup = l[0]
>>> tup 
(0, 1)
>>> x, y = tup
>>> x
0
>>> y
1
>>> t, u = l[2] # alternatively
>>> t
2
>>> u
3
```

Comment: How would I retrieve the individual values of the tuples?

Comment: @LoveMeow Will edit to show.

Answer (score 2):

I would use defaultdict for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
array = defaultdict(list)
array[(1,2,3)].append(1)
array[(1,2,3)].append(2)
```

Now array at position (1,2,3) is a list containing 1 and 2

Comment: Overkill. You don't need a dictionary.

Comment: How would I retrieve the individual values?

Comment: Just with array[(1,2,3)]. This will give you your values as a list. E.g.: result = array[(1,2,3)]

Answer (score 2):

If understand correctly, you can store new `list` with values you need in `array[1][2][3]` instead of single value:

```
array[1][2][3] = [1]  # instead of = 1

array[1][2][3].append(2)  # now it's [1, 2]

array[1][2][3].extend([3,4])  # now it's [1, 2, 3, 4]

all_values = array[1][2][3]  # no another dimensions uses to get values
```

Answer (score 1):

> array[1][2][3] = 1,2

Seems like you want to have a list in array[1][2][3], which you could actually do with

```
array[1][2][3] = [1,2]
```

or alternatively, as already mentionned by others with variations of

```
array[1][2][3] = []
array[1][2][3].append(1)
array[1][2][3].extend([2])
```

Mind the fact that use of t-uples is also possible

```
array[1][2][3] = (1,2)
```

But in this case, you won't be able to extend your "list" nor to modify its content (t-uples are indeed constant arrays, in size as well as in content.).

> Is there a way of doing this without having to introduce another
>   dimension to the array?

Well... this requirement seems rather antagonistic with your previous one.

> array[1][2][3] = 1,2

suggests that your are able to differentiate between "array[1][2][3][0]" (=1) and "array[1][2][3][1]" (=2). So, unless I don't understand your question, the short answer is "no" :)